# Simultaneous CSS hover effect on 2 separate menu elements without wrapper?

Tags: css, navigation, hover, menuitem, semantic-markup

The navigation menu of a fictitious company is as follows:

[image]

The company specialises in the made-up, "Crab [Sitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_sitting)", but offers two other services that are targeted at people's [anthropod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod) pets.

It has been decided that the link to "Services" in the navigation should lead to "Pet Crab Sitting" right away — without a general page about their services.

That is easy to do with HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/services/crab-sitting/">Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/services/crab-sitting/">Crab Sitting</a></li>
            <li><a href="/services/polishing-crustacean-shells/">Polishing Crustacean Shells</a></li>
            <li><a href="/services/massages-for-anthropods/">Massages for Anthropods</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

But from a UX standpoint, a rollover effect that will change both is necessary to clarify that the two lead to one place.

In other words, making it appear that the two list elements are one link.

How can a `:hover` effect be achieved on "Services" and "Crab Sitting" at the same time with CSS, but without sacrificing HTML semantics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

else, you may as well filter from href :
This way, it doesn't matter much where similar href link stands, as long as it's being a child within adjacent ul .
http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/b5Lzn/

```
[href*="crab-sitting"]:hover,  [href*="crab-sitting"]:hover + ul [href*="crab-sitting"] {
    background:green;
}
```

and if in second link, you forget last slash on href, it still works;
http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/b5Lzn/1/

```
<li><a href="/services/crab-sitting/ ">Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/services/crab-sitting ">Crab Sitting</a></li>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, how is browser support?

Comment: No IE6 - unfortunate because it's the most common browser in the crab sitting community

Comment: you're being brave ! I haven't fixed IE6 issues for over a year. Don't you use any things like this http://selectivizr.com/ , at least for CCS2.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

the best you can do is:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZVUu2/2/

```
a.blah:hover
    {color: red;}

a.blah:hover + ul > li > a.blah
    {color:red;}

<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="blah" href="/services/crab-sitting/">Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="blah" href="/services/crab-sitting/">Crab Sitting</a></li>
            <li><a href="/services/massages-for-anthropods/">Massages for Anthropods</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When "Crab Sitting" is selected, "Services" doesn't select

Comment: indeed, as i said, this is the best you can do with css... :( you should try a js solution

Answer (score 0):

```
li:hover{
 This is for the event on the main li
}

li:hover ul li:first-child{
 here you have selected the first element of the nested ul when the main li is hovered
}
```

Happy coding

Comment: I didn't want to clutter the question, but I've already tried that, [it doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVUu2/) — plus, I'd like to target the `<a>` elements and not the `<li>`

Comment: if you add 
    `li:hover ul li:first-child a{
 
    }`
it will work and the anchor will be in red, the problem is that the style of the ul is inherited from the parent list item.

So you have to add this snippet 
`li ul{
    color: #000;
}`

Comment: This is effectively working, tried it on your fiddle
`li:hover > a{
    color: red;
}

li:hover ul li:first-child a{
    color: red;
}`

Comment: with that, it also gets highlighted when on other options